# Adding an Item from a string to insert into the database table

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to add an item from a string to insert into a table along with the other information. I have followed a tutorial for a shopping cart and I am in need of adding the total cost to the record. I have the item in the array and have added what I believe to be the items I need. What I am having an issue with is implementing it in the controller side of the project. Below is the code I have, I am not 100% sure if what I added for the total price is correct. This should be in decimal form. thank for your help.

Shopping Cart CSHTML page. This is not the whole page just relevant parts.

```
               using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrder", "Parts", new { id = "f" }))
               {
                  <table id="tableOrder" class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Part Number</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Qty Selected</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Total Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var parts in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@parts.Material</td>
                            <td>@string.Format("{0:C2}", parts.SellingPrice)</td>
                            <td>@parts.QtySelected</td>
                            <td>@parts.Description</td>
                            <td>@string.Format("{0:C2}", (parts.SellingPrice * parts.QtySelected))</td>
                        </tr>
                        totalOrder += (parts.QtySelected * parts.SellingPrice);

                        @Html.HiddenFor(p => parts.Material)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(p => parts.QtySelected)

                    }
                </table>
                <!-- TOTAL PRICE-->
                <h4 style="margin-left: 66%;">Total : <span class="label label-info">@string.Format("{0:C2}", totalOrder)</span></h4>
                     @Html.HiddenFor(p => totalOrder)
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="SaveOrder" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#additionalInfo">Save Order</button>
                </div> <!-- MODAL FOOTER-->
    }
```

Java Script portion.

```
        $("#SaveOrder").click(function () {

        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var dataPart = $form.serializeArray();

        console.log(dataPart);

        var arrIdPart = [];
        var arrQtyPart = [];
        var totalPrice = [];

        for (i = 0; i < dataPart.length; i++)
        {
            if (dataPart[i].name == 'parts.Material')
            {
                arrIdPart.push(dataPart[i].value);
            }
            else if (dataPart[i].name == 'parts.QtySelected')
            {
                arrQtyPart.push(dataPart[i].value);

            }
            else if (dataPart[i].name == 'totalOrder')
            {
                totalPrice.push(dataPart[i].value);
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("AddOrder", "Parts")',
            data: { arrIdPart, arrQtyPart },
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.data == true)
                {
                    alert("Order has saved successfully ");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Order did not save successfully ! ");
                }

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Order did not collect data successfully ! ");
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the controller action. I have added the parts to all of these that have to do with totalPrice. The issue is how to implement it in the record add to customer.

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrder(string[] arrIdPart, int[] arrQtyPart, decimal[] totalPrice)
    {
        int countPart = arrIdPart.Length;
        int CompanyId = (int)Session["CompanyId"];
        bool statusTran = false;
```

EDIT - added

```
        decimal totPrice = totalPrice.Length;
```

---

```
        CustomerEntities _context = new CustomerEntities();

        using (DbContextTransaction dbTran = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                CompanyNames customer = _context.CompanyNames.Find(CompanyId);

                if (customer != null)
                {
```

EDIT - Changed this

```
                    customer.Ordered.Add(new Orders { OrderDate = DateTime.Now, TotalPrice = totPrice });
```

---

```
                }

                Orders orderSelected = customer.Ordered.LastOrDefault();

                if (orderSelected != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < countPart; i++)
                    {
                        Parts selectedPart = _context.Parts.Find(arrIdPart[i]);
                        orderSelected.OrderDetail.Add(new OrderDetails { Parts = selectedPart, Quantity = arrQtyPart[i] });
                    }
                }

                //Save Changes
                int countResult = _context.SaveChanges();

                //Commit Transaction
                dbTran.Commit();

                if (countPart > 0)
                {
                    statusTran = true;
                    partsList.Clear();
                }


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbTran.Rollback();
            }
        }


        return Json(new { data = statusTran }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

However I am not getting anything for totalOrder in the script. Says its null. But in my 'console.log(dataPart);' In the console it is there with the name totalOrder.

Comment: You're letting the end user (customer) provide a value for the total price?!

Answer (score 0):

Not saying it's the final answer but I can't put multiline code in a comment..

I wish to point out that you don't post the total price you calculated, to the server:

```
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AddOrder", "Parts")',
        data: { arrIdPart, arrQtyPart }, //look, no totalprice data? You did all those efforts to calc it and then did nothing with it?
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.data == true)
```

totalPrice should probably be called arrSubtotalPart by the way, for consistency..

Warning: The server receives the items and the quantities, it should work the price out from that rather than let the end user dictate how much he wants to pay for an order by manipulating the JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for that. It was late and my brain was shutting down I guess. I do now get the data part for that but for some reason it is not posting successfully. From what I can see it Is getting everything it needs. no errors. it is going to the else alert for if(response.data == true). In your Warning I am confused on what you mean, I understand the manipulation but am confused on where to have that take place. Do you mean use a stored procedure to calculate the total? If I grab the individual prices and work it out in the controller they will be able to manipulate that. Thanks

Comment: If I was writing a shopping site I would hav things that I know (item, price, stock level) and there would be things the user knows (how many to buy). The user should just tell me he wants 10 USB sticks, and I'll work out the price on the server side. For sure you can send the browser some info on what a usb price is, and you can even add it up for him in the basket in his browser, but there's no way you should accept the price data back from the user! You only want the quantity from him, and you say that part is working already... THe controller shall get the ajax post, pull the qty..

Comment: ..and calc the total price for the items from `request.quantity * database.price`

Comment: Okay, so maybe you did not understand what I am doing here. The part that is on this post is the "Cart", the only input the user has is to select it and give a qty of how many. The JavaScript and ajax is only for them to view what is in the cart and how much each item is with a total. I needed to get the total to put in the table for purposes of Invoice and payment process. Some will use a credit card while others may choose to use a PO#. The system is built with about 6 tables. This is a business to business website so if they are not logged into there account they will not be able to

Comment: purchase items. The parts are proprietary to there equipment. So there is a table that holds all the parts and their prices. Once they save in the cart this info gets puts into the orders and orderDetail table with their CustomerId. then they will be able to check out and use 1 of the 2 payment options. So no there is nothing in this system that lets them select the price.

Comment: But your entire question is about putting the price in the data that is POSTed (via Ajax) to the controller. Why would an ecommerce site ever need for the customer's computer to send price data to the server?

Comment: I get what you are saying, I have decided to scrap the current shopping and cart code and rewrite it. I am following the MVC Music Store tutorial. Changing some things though as this is outdated. thanks for your help.